# How to get static IP for Azure Data Factory Pipeline?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-data-factory

I have a workflow/pipeline in Azure which connects to third party FTP (via linked service) and get files on regular basis.

It was all working fine, till third party introduced white listing of IP's, and now they are asking me to provide static IP's or range. Unless white listed, I will not be able to get my pipeline working.

Now my question is. How to provide my IP address?

I know which region my ADF works in (North-Europe) and I know my linked service uses AutoResolve-IR.

Will solution be to go with, self hosted IR? If yes, then how will I know the IP of my IR?

Comment: This does not look like a [programming question](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem to support static IP addresses for Data Factory recently. Announcement: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/azure-data-factory-now-supports-static-ip-address-ranges/ba-p/1117508

Here is the list of IPs for North Europe as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses

[image]